# How to have a button create an object in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an inventory class for my independent study, and one of the tabs for the app will be a list of supplies a person has. I want to be able to create an "add button" in the navigation bar of the page to create another item to the list that a user can edit. For example, in the alarm app for iPhone, there is a plus button in the top right that creates another alarm for the person to edit or delete again.

Comment: I think this question is too broad.. are you simply asking people how to make a button trigger an action? or are you asking people to complete your whole project?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `UIBarButtonItem` to the navigation bar `rightBarButtonItem` property. When instanciating that item you can add an action that is messaged, when the button is pressed.

You can also do this in Interface Builder if you are using XIBs or storyboards. Look for tutorials with the keyword UIBarButtonItem in them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var addButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "addMethod")

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
```